# Unable to pass LocalDate as JSON parameter

Tags: json, jpa, spring-data-jpa, json-deserialization

I am unable to pass a LocalDate object to my controller method. Postman is telling me that there is a JSON parse error.

This is the entity field I am trying to fetch by:

```
private LocalDate transactionDate;
```

My repository method

```
    List<Transactions> findAllByTransactionDateLike(LocalDate transactionDate);
```

My controller method:

```
  @GetMapping
    public List<Transactions> fetchBankStatementByMonth(@RequestBody LocalDate transactionDate) {
        return transactionService.findAllByTransactionDateLike(transactionDate);
    }
```

My Postman Body:

```
{
    "transactionDate":"2021-12"
}
```

The error:

```
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"
```

Comment: `@RequestBody` is used with `@PostMapping`

Answer (score 2):

for a @GetMapping, try

```
@GetMapping
public List<Transactions> fetchBankStatementByMonth(
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) 
    LocalDate transactionDate) {
```

and sending the request in the query param

e.g
`http://localhost:8080/your-endpoint?transactionDate=2021-12-27`

---

if input contains only year and month, the @RequestParam would be better represented by `java.time.YearMonth`

```
@GetMapping
public List<Transactions> fetchBankStatementByMonth(
    java.time.YearMonth transactionYearMonth) {
```

followed by conversion to LocalDate to the day of your choosing

e.g. for 1st day of the month:

`LocalDate transactionDate = LocalDate.of(transactionYearMonth.getYear(), transactionYearMonth.getMonthValue(), 1);`

---

it looks like you want to do a search by the month (not a specific day)
you might need to change your service method
to be something like `findAllByTransactionDateBetween(startDate, endDate)`

and convert the input YearMonth value to 1st day of month and last day of month, then call your new/updated service method

```
//1st day of month
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(transactionYearMonth.getYear(), transactionYearMonth.getMonthValue(), 1);

//last day of month
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(transactionYearMonth.getYear(), transactionYearMonth.getMonthValue(), transactionYearMonth.lengthOfMonth());

return transactionService.findAllByTransactionDateBetween(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: Great one, it works, thank you! Can I somehow make it possible to search by month, without specifying the day?

Comment: maybe try sending 2 params individually? for year and the other for month?

Comment: @melinteteofil added an alternate option using `YearMonth`

Comment: YearMonth sadly returns empty, my DB has values, but the list displayed in Postman is empty

Comment: I should change the entity field to YearMonth aswell, right?

Comment: @atish.s I do not know how to use that to then fetch an actual date from the DB

Comment: updated with one more note to convert from transactionYearMonth (of type YearMonth) to transactionDate (of type LocalDate)

Comment: Wow it finally works, thank you so much <3 @indybee

Comment: @melinteteofil Glad it is working Cheers